The Reforger NPC is stuck underground. How do I get him to move?
In Terraria, the Reforger NPC is stuck underground. How do I get him to move?
He's stuck in the caves; I've checked my rooms, and he hasn't moved in yet. Am I missing something, or is he generally stuck way down there?

You mean the Goblin Tinkerer. If you've unbound him and he's just wandering around as the Goblin Tinkerer, then it's the same issue as My steampunker won't spawn even with all of the requirements fulfilled?
You have to make them a suitable house, then they will move in once you leave them off the screen at night, unless you get lucky and it's thundering right now and they're off-screen.
If you want to speed things up, while keeping them in view, perhaps you could make them a house in-place. You'd need explosives to remove the existing walls first, if you want to be fast about it.

Note that they will only automatically teleport home at night or during a thunderstorm! They will continue to wander in the caves if left off-screen during day time.

@Smurfy7777 - Thanks! Addiing!
